# How to run ASP.NET Composite C1 on Mac OS X localhost?

Tags: asp.net, macos, c1-cms

Im mostly an frontender, so Im pretty satisfied with that I even got ASP.NET up and running on my Mac. What I *think* I have done is installing all things necessary to run a project. At least I can now create a project with

```
yo aspnet
```

and run it with

```
dnx web
```

I can also see the scaffolding created by Yeoman in Visual Studio Code. Everything is fine.

My problem is, when Im trying to run a project that one of the Windows developers have asked me to work on. I clone the repo but when I try to run dnx web is says:

```
Error: Unable to resolve project from /Volumes/Diverse/Doks/Erhverv/Kimik IT/git-repo/XYZ
```

I also notice that there is no project.json or startup.cs-file in the project. It looks like this:

http://oi64.tinypic.com/21bvqfk.jpg

Its a site with Composite C1 CMS - what do I need to do to be able to run it on localhost:5000 ?

Every input much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please accept my answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, C1 5.0 requires full .net framework 4.5.1 which only runs on Windows, so neither Mono og Asp.Net Core will work.

See also https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS/issues/94#issuecomment-206229567